# Scala:Handling special encoding characters in String

Tags: scala

I have string containing many umlauts`(ä,ö,ü)` and euro`(€)` symbol. Is there any library or existing methods that transform them to `(a,o,u)` and `Euro(or its equivalent)` respectively in Scala.

I am aware of the similar libraries in python that do the job but can't seem to find it in scala.

Consider this example : `val String="Köln and München are great cities. The average bus ticket costs €4.5"`

I want to be converted something like this or equivalent: `"Koln and Munchen are great cities. The average bus ticket costs Euros 4.5"`

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own translator with whatever rules you need to apply.

```
val str="Köln and München are great cities. The average bus ticket costs €4.5"

val deUm :Map[Char,String] =
  Map('ö'->"o", 'ü'->"u", '€'->"Euros ").withDefault(_.toString)

str.flatMap(deUm(_))
//res0: String = Koln and Munchen are great cities. The average bus ticket costs Euros 4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a library for this? you can just use the string replace function like shown here?

http://gordon.koefner.at/blog/coding/replacing-german-umlauts/